# Context errors in CABasicAnimation animation

Tags: ios, calayer, cgcontext, cabasicanimation

I have the stroke animation:

```
- (void)drawBezierAnimate:(BOOL)animate
{

UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 0.562 blue: 0.343 alpha: 1];

UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [self bezierPath];


CAShapeLayer *bezier = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

bezier.path          = bezierPath.CGPath;
bezier.lineCap       = kCALineCapRound;
bezier.strokeColor   = color.CGColor;
bezier.fillColor     = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
bezier.strokeStart   = 1.0;
bezier.strokeEnd     = 0.0;
bezier.lineWidth     = 8.0;
bezier.strokeStart   = 0.0;
bezier.strokeEnd     = 1.0;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:bezier];


if (animate)
   {
    CABasicAnimation *animateStrokeStart = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeStart"];
    animateStrokeStart.duration  = appDelegate.myPlayer.audioPlayer.duration;
    animateStrokeStart.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    animateStrokeStart.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    [bezier addAnimation:animateStrokeStart forKey:@"strokeStartAnimation"];
   }
}
```

Animation works perfect, but I am getting the errors:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetLineJoin: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetLineCap: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetMiterLimit: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

Path for animation is:

```
   - (UIBezierPath *)bezierPath
{


    //// Color Declarations
    UIColor* color0 = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.756 green: 0.756 blue: 0.756 alpha: 0.6];



    //// Bezier Drawing
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];


    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(213.79, 170.83)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(131.93, 95) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(212.14, 128.68) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(176.13, 95)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(50, 173.85) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(86.68, 95) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(50, 130.3)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(131.93, 252.7) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(50, 217.4) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(86.68, 252.7)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(157.55, 248.76) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(140.88, 252.7) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(149.49, 251.32)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(209.69, 281) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(166.59, 267.78) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(186.54, 281)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(267, 225.85) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(241.34, 281) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(267, 256.31)];
    [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(213.79, 170.83) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(267, 196.71) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(243.53, 172.86)];
    [bezierPath closePath];


    [color0 setStroke];
    bezierPath.lineWidth = 11;
    [bezierPath stroke];

    return bezierPath;
}
```

I know that I need to get currentContext if I want something to draw, but this is an animatiom and I even don't have drawRect:

How to get rid of these annoying errors?

Comment: These sorts of errors usually happen when someone tries calling `drawRect` themselves or something strange like that. There's nothing wrong with this code and it works fine for me. Where are you calling `drawBezierAnimate`? Do you have any `UIView` subclass, too, that might be lingering about? Bottom line, the problem is not with the above code, but rather either how you're calling it or something else lingering about in your project.

Comment: By the way, `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` is not needed when you're working with `CAShapeLayer` objects like you are here.

Comment: I added path creation code. Please check it out.

Comment: Thank you Rob! Your hint completely solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem rests with the `bezierPath` method. Remove the lines that say:

```
[color0 setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 11;
[bezierPath stroke];
```

The `CAShapeLayer` does all of the drawing for you. The `bezierPath` should just define the path, itself, but not perform any of the visual rendering. Let `CAShapeLayer` do that for you.